# How can i get value from promise array?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have a code which has an array of Promises

```js
async function getResult(){
  ...
  //resultPromise  ==> it has promise in array Ex.[Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }]
  let finalResult = await resultPromise.map((result) => {
    //result has each promise from promise array
    result.then((obj) => {
      return obj.data
    })
  })
}
```

From this I want to get `obj.data` stored in the variable `finalResult`. How can I do that?

I tried below ways

```js
return resultPromise.map((result)=>{
    result.then((obj)=>{
      console.log(obj.data)
      return obj.data
    })
  })
```

or

```js
resultPromise.map((result)=>{
    result.then((obj)=>{
      console.log(obj.data)
      return obj.data
    })
  })
```

I know the chaining way but, I couldn't get the correct value from it.

Comment: I can't believe I can't find a duplicate for this... If someone without a dupe-hammer finds one, feel free to notify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.all`.

```
async function getResult(){
  ...  
  let finalResult = (await Promise.all(resultPromise)).map((obj) => obj.data);
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you i solve it. Your help has helped me a lot. Have a nice day:)